# Telerik Grid, Detail view - how to specify route values

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, telerik

I've just started using Telerik, to speed up some of my development, however I'm stuck trying to bring up a normal MVC Details page from a Grid Component.

All I want, is a select button to send the user to something like /Person/Details/5

The reason why I want a separate page (rather than a popup) is that some of the data relationships are complex, and it's better experience that these are displayed in it's own page, rather than a popup.

My model has a few objects, that's why you see the p.person.Title type setup below.

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
   .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.person.Title).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.person.Firstname);
            columns.Bound(p => p.person.Firstname);
            columns.Bound(p => p.person.Surname);
            columns.Bound(p => p.person.ABN).Width(210);
            columns.Bound(p => p.person.PracticeCode);
            columns.Bound(p => p.currentform);
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit();  });
            columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy();  });
            columns.Command(command => { command.Select(); });
        })
    .Sortable()
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Server()

        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.person.personkey))
        .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Person"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Details", "Person" ))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Person"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "Person"))
```

The grid itself is working fine, however, when someone selects the "Select" button, I want them to go to the /Person/Details/{id}  page.   Telerik is almost doing it right, it's sending the user to 
/Person/Details?grid-mode=select&person.personkey=11   (I actually want /Person/Details/11 )

So, I noticed that the "Read" method has a few different signatures to enable route values, but I just can't seem to rig it up to get the right route values.

I've tried....

```
.Read(read => read.Action("Details", "Practitioner", p => p.practitioner.drkey ))
```

and combinations of, but I just can't seem to get the right route value in there.

How do I correctly specify the right route values ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended by solving this with a Template. 
Not exactly the outcome I was looking for, but close enough at this stage.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.person.pkey).Template(@<text>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details" , "Details" , new { id = @item.person.pkey })
            </text>);
```

The trick is that a traditional MVC razor action is placed inside a Telerik Template.

It also removed the need for the .Select and .Read rows.